# How to apply condition in PySpark to keep null only if one else remove nulls

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Condition:**

- If **ID** has a **Score** 'High' or 'Mid' -> remove None
- If **ID** only has **Score** None -> just keep None

**Input:**

| ID | Score |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | High |
| AAA | Mid |
| AAA | None |
| BBB | None |

**Desired output:**

| ID | Score |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | High |
| AAA | Mid |
| BBB | None |

I'm having difficulty in writing the if condition in PySpark. Is there any other way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count `Score` over window partitioned by `ID`, then filter on `Score` is not null or the count is 0 :

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "count_scores",
    F.count("Score").over(Window.partitionBy("ID"))
).where("Score IS NOT NULL OR count_scores = 0")\
 .drop("count_scores")

df1.show()

#+---+-----+
#| ID|Score|
#+---+-----+
#|BBB| null|
#|AAA| High|
#|AAA|  Mid|
#+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a flag of whether all scores are null, and filter the rows where the score is not null or when flag is true (all scores are null):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'flag', 
    F.min(F.col('Score').isNull()).over(Window.partitionBy('ID'))
).filter('flag or Score is not null').drop('flag')

df2.show()
+---+-----+
| ID|Score|
+---+-----+
|BBB| null|
|AAA| High|
|AAA|  Mid|
+---+-----+
```